# Выдаёт ошибку при выводе среднего арифметического

Tags: python

Требуется сделать вывод, но выдаёт ошибку typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
Мой код:

```
first_num = input ()
sec_num = input ()
third_num = input ()
mean_num = (first_num + sec_num + third_num)/3
print(mean_num)
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы вычисления выводились в виде строки?

Answer (score 0):

`input()` ---> `float(input())`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @VoltTheHusky, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.